# C++ Error C2440

Tags: random, textbox, numbers, c++-cli, ostringstream

I am trying to create a random number generator in C++, which puts the result in a textBox.

I get the error 'error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' to 'System::String ^

My code is:

```
int rnd = 1 + rand() % 100;
std::ostringstream convert;
convert << rnd;
String ^ num = convert.str();
textBox1->Text = num;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are missing a language tag. `String ^ num = ...` is not C++.

Comment: What do you mean? Sorry, I'm new to C++ (C#/VB.NET)

Comment: looks like microsoft managed c++ code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot assign a `std::string` to a `System::String`. The first one is ISO c++ and the second one Microsoft C++/CLI.

As suggested [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/84d0d4f7-9277-4e04-ad17-65abd3f3daf4/converting-between-systemstring-stdstring-and-char),
you can do something like this

```
String^ num = gcnew System::String(convert.str().c_str());
```

Comment: I got the error: "error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const char *' to 'System::String ^'". What do I do?

Comment: Sorry I thought there would be an implicit conversion. My fault.

Answer (score -1):

The .Net way is

```
textBox1-> Text = rnd.ToString ();
```

ostringstream is a lousy way to do that conversion even in native C++.